# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Have this error :

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  on db_seller_brands= models.Seller_brands(seller_brand)
```

when I try to make a POST API request.

CRUD :

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models, schemas

def create_seller(db: Session, seller: schemas.Seller):
    db_seller_brands= models.Seller(seller)
    db.add(db_seller)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_seller)
    return db_seller
```

POST :

```
@app.post("/create_seller/")
def create_seller(seller:schemas.Seller):
    session = Session()
    return CRUD.create_seller(session,seller)
```

OBS.: im using FASTAPI and i already set CONFIG class on schema pydantic.

Comment: The `seller` model does not accept a positional argument; if you're going to give it any arguments, it needs to be keyword arguments. If the names between your pydantic model and database model are identical, you could probably use `**seller.dict()` to expand the pydantic model into keyword arguments, but you need to make sure that it's safe to do so (i.e. no user controlled keys, etc.)

Comment: Check the definition for `__init__` in your `models.Seller` class. It is likely defined as `__init__(self)`, which is only one argument, and you are trying to pass two (the self argument and `seller`)

Comment: **seller.dict() Works for me ! Thank you guys !